# Can I mix Persistent FSM and at-least-once-message delivery in Akka

Tags: akka-persistence, akka-fsm

Akka provides

1. A Persistent Actor with at-least-once message deliver ([link](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#At-Least-Once_Delivery))
2. A Persistent FSM ([link](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html#Persistent_FSM))

Can I mix the two? I want to be able to maintain a persistent state machine, but also have stage changes trigger events which send messages to other actors with at-least-once message deliver guarantee

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question myself, and since there was no answer anywhere on the net - I took it to the akka user list.

In short, it should work but was not tested. Moreover, there's no Java API available for the mixin of the above two traits.

I plan to test such a mixin in the next month or two and provide feedback.

See the following for more details:

1. [Akka user list topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/mJTjpClYjbw)
2. [Akka ticket to track the issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/22457)